# Convert table data and reformat

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have table named `Table`

| id | Level1 | Level2 | Level3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | CA | 13000 |
| 2 | FR | PA | 30000 |
| 3 | US | CA | 24000 |
| 4 | US | LA | 10000 |
| 5 | UK | LN | 500 |
| 6 | UK | LN | 600 |
| 7 | FR | PA | 888 |
| 8 | FR | DF | 1000 |

and I would like to convert it to the (First Conversion) below format which will sum `Level2`  and column group by Level1 ' as below

```sql
select Level1, level2, sum(level3) as level3
from table
group by level2
order by level1
```

Then (Second Conversion)  combining the common rows which had the same `Level1` to be like below

[image: Table Conversion]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider grouping your data and using [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as shown below

**Conversion 1**

The code below groups by `Level1` and `Level2` and sums `Level3` before renaming it to `LEVEL3`

```
SELECT
    Level1,
    Level2,
    SUM(Level3) as Level3
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
    Level1,
    Level2;
```

| Level1 | Level2 | Level3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | CA | 37000 |
| FR | PA | 30888 |
| US | LA | 10000 |
| UK | LN | 1100 |
| FR | DF | 1000 |

---

**Conversion 2**

The query below uses the results from the previous query as a subquery (may also be used as a CTE if desired) and uses the `STRING_AGG` function to concatenate the grouped results based on `LEVEL1`. You may additionally order the results if desired.

```sql
    
SELECT
    Level1,
    STRING_AGG(Level2,',') as Level2,
    STRING_AGG(Level3,',') as Level3
FROM (
    SELECT
        Level1,
        Level2,
        SUM(Level3) as Level3
    FROM
        my_table
    GROUP BY
        Level1,
        Level2
) t
GROUP BY
    Level1
```

| Level1 | Level2 | Level3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FR | PA,DF | 30888,1000 |
| UK | LN | 1100 |
| US | CA,LA | 37000,10000 |

---

[Working example on db-fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d6f189714d20f414315f3ff7fcfe9864)

#### Edit 1:

For SQL Server Versions not supporting `STRING_AGG`, the following approach using JOINs and CROSS APPLY with `FOR XML PATH` to Concatenate the columns may be used:

```sql
WITH group_1 as (
    SELECT
        Level1,
        Level2,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),SUM(Level3)) as Level3
    FROM
        my_table
    GROUP BY
        Level1,
        Level2
),
level2_grouped AS (
    SELECT
        Level1,
        LEFT(MergedValues,LEN(MergedValues)-1) AS Level2
    FROM group_1 extern
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            Level2+','
        FROM
            group_1 intern
        WHERE
            extern.Level1 = intern.Level1
        FOR XML PATH('')
    )merged(MergedValues)
),
level3_grouped AS (
    SELECT
        Level1,
        LEFT(MergedValues,LEN(MergedValues)-1) AS Level3
    FROM group_1 extern
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            Level3+','
        FROM
            group_1 intern
        WHERE
            extern.Level1 = intern.Level1
        FOR XML PATH('')
    )merged(MergedValues)
)
SELECT
    g1.Level1,
    l2.Level2,
    l3.Level3
FROM 
    group_1 g1
INNER JOIN 
    level2_grouped l2 ON g1.Level1 = l2.Level1
INNER JOIN 
    level3_grouped l3 ON g1.Level1 = l3.Level1
GROUP BY
    g1.Level1,
    l2.Level2,
    l3.Level3
```

or simplier

```sql
WITH group_1 as (
    SELECT
        Level1,
        Level2,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),SUM(Level3)) as Level3
    FROM
        my_table
    GROUP BY
        Level1,
        Level2
),
level_grouped AS (
    SELECT
        Level1,
        LEFT(Merged2Values,LEN(Merged2Values)-1) AS Level2,
        LEFT(Merged3Values,LEN(Merged3Values)-1) AS Level3
    FROM group_1 extern
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            Level2+','
        FROM
            group_1 intern
        WHERE
            extern.Level1 = intern.Level1
        FOR XML PATH('')
    )merged2(Merged2Values)
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            Level3+','
        FROM
            group_1 intern
        WHERE
            extern.Level1 = intern.Level1
        FOR XML PATH('')
    )merged3(Merged3Values)
)
SELECT
    Level1,
    Level2,
    Level3
FROM 
    level_grouped g1
GROUP BY
    Level1,
    Level2,
    Level3
```

[Working db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8919993366b698cd34bec2af9f6a9526)

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Thanks a lot , it's working fine but with MSSQL 2017 and later versions. My DB version is 2012 .

Comment: @tamersalem I added an alternative approach in an edit to the answer. Let me know if this works for you.